# If all variable / function names in C must be unique, then how is there no clash in standard library?

Tags: c

I cannot understand this about C. Since every variable and function has to be unique (since they are global) then how can this be possible with a huge library like the standard C library and 3rd party libraries? Yes you could make every variable "static" but that does not seem to be the case.

For example I was looking and I found this `random_data` struct `stdlib.h` and I am wondering - what are the chances that another library also has a struct called `random_data`? Won't that be a clash?

**stdlib.h**

```
struct random_data {
  int32_t *fptr;
  int32_t *rptr;
  ...
};
```

I mean what if both `stdlib` and `stdio` have a struct called `random_data` and I was to include both libraries in my program? The standard library has thousands of functions and variables and it seems impossible that they all would be unique. Also what about 3rd party libraries? What if a 3rd party library also has a struct called `random_data`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

}
```

Comment: The compiler will throw an error in that case. And generally speaking, programmers should use a prefix to prevent these clashes. In some other languages that support namespaces, this is less of a problem.

Comment: This post needs to focus on *one* question.

Comment: You mean a clash *within* the standard library? Because the authors made sure there isn't. Many third party libraries use a prefix, as stated, to try to make sure there isn't a clash with *other* third party libraries. That is more of a potential problem than a collision with your own code, where you are in a position to rename things.

Comment: C does not have a global namespace. It has file scope and external linkage, which is different. `struct random_data` is not a variable or function and has no linkage. It can appear in a source file (not a header file) without interfering with any other source file. It should not appear in `stdlib.h` except as protected by some `#if` guard so that it is only used when features beyond the C standard are requested.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right there is `# ifdef __USE_MISC` around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C standard library was designed specifically so that there are not any clashes. You are right, that's kinda delicate, that's why C++ introduced the concept of namespaces (So that you can have a variable called cout without it clashing with std::cout).

As for a more general case, a simple way to make a library in C while making sure no name collision ever happen is simply by using a naming convention where you prefix all your variables and functions with a particular word pertinent to the library.

For example most SDL function are prefixed by `SDL_` like `SDL_CreateThread`. Similarly OpenGL prefixes most functions with `gl` like `glViewport()`, and so on. Naming conventions for C are a whole topic, and they are the way people make sure collisions do not become a problem in general.

Edit: Some more examples and extra miscellaneous info

This even occurs in the standard library (Or at least the POSIX standard). All function to come out of the `pthread.h` header are prefixed by `pthread_` like `pthread_create()`.

And you get the points, naming conventions in c are kinda important. You might have come across some other interesting naming conventions. for example, there are a lot of types in c that end in `_t` like `size_t` which are a way to make it explicit that said type comes from a typedef and it is NOT a primitive of the language. The Window's win32 api is filled with it's own very complex naming convention called the Hungarian Convention in which you basically have to specify the type of every function and variable directly in it's name, for example `pszWindowTitle` is prefixed by `psz` where the `p` stands for "`p`ointer" and the  `s` means is pointing to a "`s`tring", and the `z` means the string is null terminated, meaning it ends with a "`z`ero".

Comment: You're correct that later versions of C++ *ADDED* namespaces.  But C++ didn't *INVENT* the concept.  The concept of "[namespaces"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) existed long before C++ was invented, and long before C++ added them to the language.

Comment: You are absolutely right, i'm sorry if i implied that C++ came up with namespaces, that's very much not the case. I simply meant to say that the introduction of Namespaces in the C++ language was a direct attempt at solving this very problem very much present in C.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything in your library will be kept in its header file for the reason you've thought of. I was experimenting with the example of the struct you gave, and the following program compiles **without** error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct random_data {
    int32_t *fptr;
    int32_t *rptr;
};

int main(){
    printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

Most likely the struct `random_data` isn't in the header file although it might be present in the `.c` source file.

However, note that name collision **does** cause issue. This example won't compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *getchar(void);

int main(){
    printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```